# Does CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS work in MySQLdb? Syntax?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've created a table "table2" and get warnings (table already exists) when I run my code.
I want to create the table only if it doesn't exist.
Some research [MySQL syntax website](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Database-Structure/Tables/How-to-create-table-in-MySQL)turns up the following in MySQL : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

My code:

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (2 INT)`table2`')
```

provides this warning:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(2 INT)`table2`' at line 1")
```

I have database version Database version : 5.1.54-1ubuntu4 
Thanks-Tom

Comment: Did you really mean to create a column named "2"?

Answer (score 12):

mysql syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

using the following...

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (`something` int(2))')
```

result:

```
__main__:1: Warning: Table 'table2' already exists
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! How do I kill the warning?

Comment: do `import warnings` and then `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems with the syntax of your `CREATE TABLE` command.

1. You have the table name *after* the column definitions. It should be placed before them, like this:

   `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (<column definitions>);`
2. Secondly, you are using `2` as a column name, but I'm not sure that `2` is even a valid column name. If it is, it should be quoted to distinguish it from an plain integer.

You can read more about the `CREATE TABLE` syntax at the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

First, use [the official reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) and not some random site. The docs are almost certain to be a lot better. Second, you probably meant something closer to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (columnname INT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your sql syntax.  the correct syntax for a `CREATE TABLE` statement puts the table name before the columns.  Furthermore, `2 INT` is not a valid column definition.  If you mean for the column to have the name "2" it must be quoted like

```
`2` INT
```

Or if (more likely) you want a column of two decimal digits, then the length is placed after the data type;  the column must still be given a name: `foo_column int(2)`

So altogether, you want

```
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
        foo_column INT(2))
    ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3
connexion = sqlite3.connect("bd-celebrites.sq3")
curseur = connexion.cursor()
curseur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS celebrites (nom TEXT, prenom TEXT, annee INTEGER)")
```

Comment: Some code explaining the answer or giving some context to it would be appreciated.