# 'create table if not exists' query still giving warning if table exists

Tags: python, mysql

This is my python code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db")
cursor.execute("USE my_db")
table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1`  (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `rank` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )"""
cursor.execute(table)
```

It ran perfectly the first time when the db and table didn't exist. I ran it a second time to check if the `IF NOT EXIST` clause worked correctly. But it didn't! I got the following warnings:

```
script.py:67: Warning: Can't create database 'my_db'; database exists
  cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db")
script.py:79: Warning: Table 'table1' already exists
  cursor.execute(table)
```

Did I format my query incorrectly somehow? It matches everything I'm finding online as far as I can tell.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599263/making-it-pythonic-create-a-sqlite3-database-if-it-doesnt-exist

Comment: It should throw a warning; but your script shouldn't exit because of it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102251/trapping-a-mysql-warning) on how to either suppress the warnings or have them raised as exceptions.

Comment: @Rakesh that link is not relevant. OP is asking how to suppress a warning that bubbles up when creating a table that already exists, even when one's SQL query already supports this with 'CREATE IT NOT EXISTS" I think Landon's comment here is more relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935551/1983957